# IntelliJ IDEA 13 gives invalid error about incompatible types (Java-Scala-InterOp in Play)

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, playframework

I just upgraded from IDEA 12 to 13 (community edition) and since then I get an error in IDEA about incompatible types for my play project.

```
Option<String> authHeaderOption = requestHeader.headers().get(AUTHORIZATION);
```

requestHeader is of type play.api.mvc.RequestHeader. The error message states:

```
Incompatible types. Found: 'scala.Option<java.lang.String>', required: 'scala.Option<java.lang.String>
```

So it complains about types being incompatible but at the same moment states that required and found types are the same.

When running the app from play console everything works fine, so compilation works.

The error occurs in a java class that calls the scala play api. Before upgrading IntelliJ there was no such error so it must be an IDE issue but I have not been able to figure out what yet.

Has anyone seen this kind of error before?

Comment: Could it be something along the lines of multiple scala libraries added in the IDEA module configuration maybe?

Comment: Could be, I have been looking at that but I am still too new to IDEA to really know what to look for. Under "External Libraries" in my project I see one entry for SBT: org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.2 but when I open it there are two entries for scala-library.jar which seem to be identical and I don't see a way to remove one. I also tried to recreate the idea files from play but that did not change anything.

Comment: Okay.. simply hitting the delete key when highlighting one of the jars works. One gave an error though that the file could not be deleted but the other one could be deleted without problems and now the error seems to be gone..

Answer (score 20):

Hit the "File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart..." menu item.

Answer (score 1):

As posted in the comments above, you can delete a jar listed under a library entry by hitting the delete key. I only tried the safe delete variant and this allowed me to delete one of the two entries, the other one did yield an error and was not deleted. But this seems to have solved the problem.