# IDEA IntelliJ show message "Incompatible type" and can not fix error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, microservices

[image: Image show errror]

I have tried to click on suggestion action of IDE but it didn't change any thing and error still there. There are same class and library. It's so confusing.

Is that a problem of IDE or can I turn off that error inspection?
This is the error message:

> Required type:
>  org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate
> Provided:
>  org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate

I clicked on Quick Fix but it didn't change any thing.

Comment: Check your imports.  Maybe it is from a different package.

Comment: try to invalidate caches and restart Intelij

Comment: are you able to compile the code ?

Comment: This my my work space I ran microservices, you can see the same package, I still can run project without error

Comment: Better to post text than images.

Comment: What happens when you do that "Alt+Shift+Enter" that the window in the screenshot offers?

Comment: It didn't change any thing :(, just jumped to a line below the method

Comment: How about when you do `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart` as suggested in [this other QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37296998/2550406)?

Comment: Check if you are hitting(highly unlikely) on this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78410 ? Pretty old bug

Comment: I invalidated caches and restarted, it's still has that error

Comment: Hmm, that sounds annoying. Does the program compile? Maybe it's just a bug with the highlighting but you can just ignore it

Comment: It's okay when I run or debug all projects. I just want to turn off that error of IDE, it always show error when I code

Answer (score 1):

> It's okay when I run or debug all projects. I just want to turn off that error of IDE, it always show error when I code

You should be able to disable specific inspections, as per [Jetbrains Website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#disable-inspections).
The easiest way is probably this one:

> **Disable an inspection in the editor**
>
> 1. Place the caret at the highlighted line and press Alt+Enter (or click the Intention action icon to use the intention action).
> 2. Click the arrow next to the inspection you want to disable, and select **Disable inspection**.

Alternatively, you can also *suppress* inspections:

> When you suppress an inspection, the code analysis engine doesn't highlight the problem found by this inspection in the specific piece of code (class, method, field, or statement). You can also suppress all inspections in the current class.

After you suppress an inspection, IntelliJ IDEA adds a new element before the selected symbol.

For example in Java, if you suppress an inspection for a class, a method, or a field, the IDE adds the @SuppressWarnings annotation.

> **Suppress an inspection in the editor**
>
> 1. Place the caret at the highlighted line and press Alt+Enter (or click the Intention action icon to use the intention action).
> 2. Click the arrow next to the inspection you want to suppress, and select the necessary suppress action.
>    [image]

Comment: I decided to ignore that error by turn off highlight from Ctrl + Alt + Shift + H. I can't turn off that error in the line :(. Any way, thanks for help